# Get Current CPT taxonomy category in shortcode

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I am calling my shortcode like this which works fine but I would like to avoid defining the slug, and instead picking it up automatically from the current custom post type that the shortcode resides in.

```
[get_date_posts type="os_calendar" taxonomy="calendar_event_type" slug="football-event" ]
```

i.e. call it just like:

```
[get_date_posts type="os_calendar" taxonomy="calendar_event_type"]
```

My code is as follows:

```
    function get_date_posts($params, $content){
        $default_params = array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
            'posts_per_page'=> 5,
            'meta_key'      => 'fl_date_picker'
        );

        if (isset($params['type']) && !empty($params['type']) && post_type_exists($params['type']))
            $params['post_type'] = $params['type'];

        if (isset($params['taxonomy']) && !empty($params['taxonomy']) && taxonomy_exists($params['taxonomy']) 
            && isset($params['slug']) && !empty($params['slug']))
            $params[$params['taxonomy']] = $params['slug'];

        foreach(array('type', 'slug', 'taxonomy') as $key)
            if (isset($params[$key]))
                unset($params[$key]);

        $params = wp_parse_args($params, $default_params);

        $params['meta_query'] = array( array(
                'key' => $params['meta_key'],
                'value' => date("Ymd"),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'=> 'date'
            )
        );

//truncated...
```

Comment: You talk about CPT (custom post type) but the use of slug seems to be for a taxonomy term. Can you clarify? Do you want to get current post assigned terms from a custom taxonomy? Side note(not related with your question): I recommend to read [this question and answer about the use of isset() && !empty()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty).

Comment: So the CPT is assigned to a taxonomy and a category (slug). The shortcode will be placed on all of my CPTs which will have differing slugs but the taxonomy will be the same for all i.e. 'calendar_event_type'

Comment: and yes i want to get current post assigned slug from the custom taxonomy (if it's not defined by the user in the shortcode)

Comment: any ideas here?